# Can this expression be an integer infinitely many times under a coprimality condition

Tags: nt.number-theory

The problem is as follows. Let $p$ be a fixed prime, $s$ be an unknown integer and $\alpha,\beta$ be unknown non-negative integers. Can
$$
y=\frac{s^2}{4p}-\frac{p}{4}\pm \frac{2^{\alpha}p^{\beta}}{4p}
$$
be an integer infinitely many times such that $\gcd(s,y,p)=1$, except
$$
(s,y)=(p,\pm 2^{\alpha-2})
$$
with $\alpha\geq 2$ and $p\neq 2$?

Comment: Say, $(s,y)=(3p,2\pm 2^{\alpha-2})$ where $\alpha$ is such that $p\nmid y$.

Comment: Good spotting! As far as I see, if I take a prime $q$, then for $s=qp$ I can find infinitely many "good" $y$. What do you think: is it possible to write down all occurence or to say something about the density of the solutions?

Comment: Yes. Moreover, $q$ does not have to be prime, just an odd integer.